# 12VDC to 3 Phase 400V

Tags: 12v, three-phase, dc-ac

In order top prevent my seldom used deep well pump (3 Phase, 400V) I plan to daily spin it up for a few seconds.

Where the pump is located, the is no power supply (I operate the pump using a generator), but I can place there a 12V car battery and a solar panel for constant charging.

Is there a way to convert 12V to 3 Phase 400V power? Power is needed just for a few seconds.

The pump motor is rated 2.4A

Comment: 2.4A*400V= 960W This means with an inverter (if you could find a 400VAC inverter you'd need at least 80A from a 12V battery system and a little more to run the inverter.

Comment: 3phase inverters are available, but seem to start at 48V... and the prices make me sweat... Why not consider changing the motor to 12 or even 24V?

Comment: Pump start current may be 4x (?)  rated.  I suggest go shopping 3 Phase 400V Inverter.  https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/YASKAWA-A1000-CIMR-AB4A0005FBA-Inverter-3_60825048920.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.45.2df52dcbsTCiFz

Comment: It's extremely dangerous, but you could run a VFD by attaching batteries to the DC link terminals. A few hundred volts worth of batteries. This is dangerous.

Comment: @SolarMike Probably because it's at the bottom of a well.  The long trip down the well is going to be a problem for low voltage DC.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest off-the shelf solution is probably a 2kW inverter powering a variable frequency drive.

Answer (score 1):

While it's certainly possible to have a three phase inverter that converts 12V to three phases of 400V, consider the power that your pump needs:

P = U·I ~= 1 kW.

Do to the way this universe works, you need that 1 kW to come from somewhere, in this case your battery.

For a 12 V voltage source to produce 1 kW, you'll need more than 80 A of current from that battery. That's more than most cars will need to start.

Therefore, you'll need a very beefy 12 V battery. That'll set you back >> 100€.

The inverter needs to be very beefy, too; seeing that three-phase equipment is typically very industrial in nature, that'll set you back >> 1000€.

And at that point, you'd not have bought a single solar cell.

If you're planning to use that solar system to have off-grid power there, anyway, this might be worth investigation.

If not, I'd recommend looking into automating starting your generator.

Comment: pork may be cheaper in  Yuans (lol)  but the solution will still more than pump.  How about a VFD running at 80V/10Hz just to stir the water??

Comment: I would agree with Marcus Müller, it might get easiest / cost the least to find a way to have your generator auto-start each day to operate the pump for a few seconds.

Comment: most car batteries ar cabale of several hundered amps (even small cars, it says it on the label), and 50A won't start many cars. search `battery "what is cca"`

Comment: Jasen must admit that the last car I owned was a Fiat Punto made in 1999; its starter drew about 18 A.

Comment: I think you calculated 1 KW by multiplying 2.4A x 400V.  That only works for single-phase power.  For 3-phase you must also multiply by sqrt(3).  You're at around 1.7 kw.  Another way of thinking of that is 230 V leg-neutral x 2.4A x 3 phases.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica as well as root 3 you should include the power factor, or Cos phi - whatever you call it...

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is the voltage; a 3 phase inverter requires a DC voltage that is 141% higher than the output AC voltage, so at a simple 12VDC input, the most you can get from it is 8.5VAC and that will not be enough to power up even the control boards of a modern VFD. Typically you need at least 70% of the rated voltage, so for a 400V VFD, you will need at least 320VDC into it. So regardless of the amp rating of the batteries, you would need a minimum of 27 batteries in series to even get a VFD to power itself up.

There are what are called "boost converters" that boost the DC up from a low level to a higher level using a compex network of capacitors and diodes with a transistor with a simple firing circuit. So you CAN get a boost converter either as a stand-alone unit or built into a VFD for your pump, but this is likely what Solar Mike found that "made him sweat" about the price; this type of technology doesn't come cheap.  What you might be able to do with some research, technical expertise and a good source of cheap surplus components is to build your own DC Boost Converter to get 12VDC up top 320VDC. It will still not be cheap, but it might be cheapER.