# Generic 3 phase relay switch

Tags: relay, three-phase

I have a water fill level sensor which is capable to power a 3A single phase 230V motor.

However, I have a three phase water pump. Is there a generic "switch" / relay which "operates" on single phase but is capable to switch three phases?

Comment: Thought you would have had it up&running by now : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/442872/152903

Comment: Not yet .. it's a long term project, but I am after it. Thank's for asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You are looking for a 3-phase contactor with a 230 V AC coil.

[image]

*Figure 1. A three-phase contactor in a water pump application. Source: Wikipedia's [Contactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contactor).*